# Google Analytics - Two Experiment at Single Page

Tags: google-analytics, content-experiments

I'm implementing google analytics experiment in my website. There are certain queries and doubts I have. Please have a look:

1. Can we implement two experiment with a same page at a time ? Because to doing this, I'll have to put two experiment code in my original script and its giving me some warnings.

My case is I want to implement A/B Test Variation on two button (iOS App Download and Android App Download) at my website landing page. For this, I've create two goals for each button (Goals are linked with events that I've placed with both button clicked events).

Now for experiment, I've created experiment and selected goal and placed the experiment code at appropriate place.

What about 2nd experiment for other goal ? and how should I create it ?

I hope you clear my concern.

1. Below is one warning I'm getting while creating one experiment:

**Note: Two experiment variations do not appear in the table. More information
The following 2 experiment variations have had no sessions.**

I've checked url and everything, but not getting any clue.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the warning and the structure of your experiments, but in general you shouldn't create 2 experiments for the same page through the "normal" experiments panel.

For this kind of situations, it is much better to use the Google Content Experiments API ([Client-side](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side) or [Server-side](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-server-side)). It is a little more difficult to configure, but allows for several tests in the same page, among other advantages.

If you don't want to do this "complex" configuration, you could use some paid solution like [Optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com/) or [VWO](https://vwo.com/) (they include multivariate tests, which could be better for your use case than A/B tests).